# Make a deep json file to a flaten dataframe in R

Tags: r, json, dataframe, data-structures, flatten

From this json file : https://www.itftennis.com/tennis/api/PlayerApi/GetPlayerActivity?circuitCode=WCT&matchTypeCode=S&playerId=800305047&skip=180&surfaceCode=&take=50&year=all

which has a very deep structure (lists within lists within lists....)

I want to transform it in a flatten dataframe which can be opened on Excel for example.

I read this json file in r :

```
library(jsonlite)
json_data = jsonlite::fromJSON(txt = "https://www.itftennis.com/tennis/api/PlayerApi/GetPlayerActivity?circuitCode=WCT&matchTypeCode=S&playerId=800305047&skip=180&surfaceCode=&take=50&year=all")
json_data2 = json_data[[1]]
```

I need to transform "json_data2" in an unique dataframe which gathers all the information.

I am interested in a solution in r but also in python

Comment: Put more effort into your question:
For input, do not refer to external sources to which your question refers.
Show concretely how the flatten format should look like

Comment: When in doubt, read the documentation`?jsonlite::fromJSON` especially the section on its arguments.